# UI test: is it possible to avoid using the delay() method?

Tags: testing, karate

I've been working on a UI test for a while and here's the scenario:

1. the user enters a value in an input field
2. the value entered in this field is dynamically redisplayed in the cell of an angular table

My test would like to make sure that the value entered in the input field is indeed the one reflected in the table. The problem is that I can't retrieve the value generated in the table without using the delay() method, which should be avoided.

Here's how I go about trying to recover my value in the table:

```
When waitFor(inputLocator.pathInputLocator).input("18.00")
And mouse().move(100, 200).go().click(); // click outside input, value updated in table
* def shippingCost = text(tableLocator.pathTableLocator)
* print shippingCost // return 0 instead of the value
```

Thanks for help

****** EDIT: ******
in order to check that I'm getting the value of the input field in the table, I tried this code, but I may have misunderstood the documentation:

```
When waitFor(inputLocator.pathInputLocator).input("18.00")
And mouse().move(100, 200).go().click(); // click outside input, value updated in table


And def searchFunction =
  """
  function() {
    var results = scriptAll('tableLocator.pathTableLocator', "!_.textContent == '0'");
    return results.size() > 0 ? results : null;
  }
  """

And def getMyValue = waitUntil(searchFunction)
* print getMyValue
```

This code triggers an error on the line where I pass the function searchFunction as a parameter to waitUntil

****** NEW EDIT *******
Sorry my question is badly formulated

The locator `tableLocator.pathTableLocator` targets a table cell of  number type. it's managed by Angular's data-binding: to do this, I've created a custom 'data-e2e' attribute in my front-end code. Here's the path of this locator.

```
"pathTableLocator" : "/(//*[@data-e2e='pathTableLocator'])[2]"
```

The page is not public. It comes from a web app on which rules and user roles are defined. My code works fine if I add delay(1000) after the line:

```
And mouse().move(100, 200).go().click(); // click outside input, value updated in table
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [`waitUntil`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waituntil) syntax with a function.

This may also work, but you get the idea:

```
* waitUntil(tableLocator.pathTableLocator, "!_.textContent == '0'")
```

EDIT - since you are dealing with Angular, here is what I suggest. Get things working by directly accessing the elements you need. For example:

```
* def pathTableLocators = locateAll("div[data-e2e]")
```

Start with that and then get more specific if needed:

```
* def pathTableLocators = locateAll("div[data-e2e='pathTableLocator']")
```

Note that I am using CSS locators, which are what I would recommend.

I think what is happening is angular is rebuilding the whole page, so you can't rely on `[2]` and all that to work. If the above lines work, then you know how to write a function to do a proper `waitUntil()`.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it still doesn't work with waitUntil(), I'm going to try with the function

Comment: I've edit my post, I tried the waitUntil(function) without success, but I guess I don't understand the doc correctly.

Comment: @Olivier sorry a lot depends on what exactly `tableLocator.pathTableLocator` is and I don't have a clue. is this a public page ?

Comment: @Olivier - made some edits. sorry I can't help more. but if you can find a "similar" angular based page on the net, I can try to experiment on that